# CursorAdapter bindView optimization

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-adapter

When overriding ArrayAdapter I know is correct using a pattern like this:

```
if(view != null){
   ...create new view setting fields from data 
}else
  return view; //reuse view
```

is correct too using this pattern with CursorAdapters? My problem is that I have a textcolor which can be red or blue according to a cursor field, so I don't want any errors like a red color on a cell which has a field needing blue color.
My bindView code is something like this:

```
if(c.getString(2).equals("red"))
      textView.setTextColor(<red here>);
   else
      textView.setTextColor(<blue here>);
```

if I reuse view can I be sure that red goes on red, while blue goes on blue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `CursorAdapter`, you get layout in `newView` and bind data in `bindView`. `CursorAdapter` already do  reuse pattern in `getView` so you **don't have to do it again**. Below is the original `getView` source code.

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
    return v;
}
```

If you want further optimization using `ViewHolder Pattern` here is example: Create tag in `newView` and retrieve in `bindView`

```
    public class TimeListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private    static  class   ViewHolder  {
         int    nameIndex;
         int    timeIndex;
         TextView   name;
         TextView   time;
    }
  public TimeListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
  this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }
  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
         ViewHolder holder  =   (ViewHolder)    view.getTag();
         holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(holder.nameIndex));
         holder.time.setText(cursor.getString(holder.timeIndex));
  }
  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup  
  p parent) {
         View   view    =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_row, null);
         ViewHolder holder  =   new ViewHolder();
         holder.name    =   (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
         holder.time    =   (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.task_time);
     holder.nameIndex   =   cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow 
         (TaskProvider.Task.NAME);
         holder.timeIndex   =   cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow    
         (TaskProvider.Task.DATE);
         view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would probably add `LayoutInflater.from(context)` as a global variable set in constructor, so it won't need to be got each time `newView` is run.

Comment: Is the ViewHolder still valid today? or is there a new simpler/different way?

Comment: You can replace the ViewHolder pattern using `view.setTag(int key,Object obj)` and `view.getTag(int key)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `getView` is in `Adapter` and is not dependant from `ArrayAdapter` nor `CursorAdapter`.

recycling is always a good practice. Ensure that your code sets a colour in every situation.

Comment: start with `textView.setTextColor(<default>)` and then process colors like you do

Comment: Something like: if(view != null) view.setTextcolor(); else { <create the whole view> ?}

Comment: my pattern is rather `if (view==null) {view=layoutinflater.inflate(...)} view.setText(...);`

Comment: Or if your adapter inherits from `SimpleCursorAdapter` simply do `view=super.getView(); view.setText(...)` That way, it will be recycled and non-null