# What bindView() and newView() do in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a custom `CursorAdaptor` in my project with overridden methods `bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)` and `newView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)`.
I want to know for what `CursorAdapter` are used for and what is the difference between and uses of overriding `bindView()` and `newView()`.

I have read the [Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/) tutorial but still I didn't understood. As I'm a beginner to Android, please help me understand this concept.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12224738/995891 one is for creating a new re-usable layout, the other for binding the cursor data to that view

Comment: The basic premise of a CursorAdapter is to manage a cursor object from the database.  Here is a quote from docs: "Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget."

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In order to understand this, you must first understand how [`BaseAdapter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29) works, since [`CursorAdapter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29) is a subclass of `BaseAdapter`.

Android maintains a pool of views for a `ListView` which it will give to you so you can reuse it instead of creating a new view each time.

In `BaseAdapter`, you will have a function called [`getView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29), to which one of the parameters is a `View` object named `convertView`. Basically, this `convertView` will be `null` if the list is being loaded for the first time, and it will not be `null` once you start sliding the list. Therefore, in the `getView()` method of your `BaseAdapter`, you will check if `convertView` is `null`. If yes, you will inflate it. Then you can use the view and set its elements as normal. This will improve the scrolling performance of a listview tremendously.

A `CursorAdapter` makes it easy to use when the data source of a listview is a database. In a cursor adapter, however, Android takes care of checking whether the `convertView` is `null` or not. In the [`newView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29) method, you simply inflate the view and return it. In the [`bindView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29) method, you set the elements of your view.

As an example, imagine a listview on a device which can show upto 11 list items on the screen. In this case, `newView()` will be called upto 11 times. However, `bindView()` will be called many times whenever you scroll the list view. The 11 views you created in your newView method will be reused again and again as you scroll the list.

Comment: What about the ViewHolder pattern? Is there still use for it today in JB and all the new api's?

Comment: `ViewHolder` is now deprecated in favour of using `void setTag(int, object)` and `object getTag(int)` which lets you attach references to any sub-views to the parent view (`setTag(R.id.thing, thingView)`) and then get them back quickly (`getTag(R.id.thing)` would return `thingView`).

Comment: @AndrewWyld, That's the ViewHolder pattern - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

Comment: @Yosi199, By `ViewHolder` pattern, I assume you're referring to this - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

In my personal experience, hardware which runs `Jellybean` won't give you a noticeable difference as long as you reuse the `convertView` properly. However, I still use the `ViewHolder` pattern as I find it allows me to manage the views nicely and abstract away some methods as `Viewholder.getHolderForView(View v)`

Comment: @AndrewWyld, My mistake, that isn't the `ViewHolder` pattern. @Yosi199, `ViewHolder` is not exactly deprecated, but it can cause issues pre-ICS if you use it with the `setTag(int key, Object holder)` method because of how indexed tags were implemented pre-ICS.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy I'm trying to find the dev blog I read it on, and I can't!  Anyway, `setTag(int, object)` and `getTag(int)` does all the same work `ViewHolder` does and I heard it was considered a cleaner method.  Or you can make a custom view class :)

Comment: @AndrewWyld, That particular dev blog had the post removed for some reason.. :-).. Yes, I know it does, but using `ViewHolder` with setTag(int, holder) would cause serious issues in pre-ICS. I still prefer ViewHolder simply because I find the implementation cleaner... I just have to be careful with pre-ICS devices.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy just to be clear, though, I'm not typically using `ViewHolder`, just the tags ... does that cause issues?

Comment: On Pre-ICS devices, if you use `setTag(int, tag)` where `tag` holds a reference to a `View`, then you'll end up leaking the entire view and its context(most likely, an Activity). Otherwise, you're safe.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for all this info. I'm gonna use the ViewHolder pattern for my current app since it's JB only buy I would really appreciate if you could show me how it's done without the ViewHolder?

Comment: Really helpful for freshers of android, Help me for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196322/edittext-in-gridview-how-to-get-value-from-edittext

Comment: @VinaySShenoy as you said "On Pre-ICS devices, if you use setTag(int, tag) where tag holds a reference to a View, then you'll end up leaking the entire view and its context(most likely, an Activity). Otherwise, you're safe. –" 
then how to reuse views pre-ics with view holder or with without holder it would be same case...not getting exactly

Comment: @AkhilDad Not quite. On pre-ICS devices, you'll use the `setTag()` method which doesn't cause the leak. The leak is caused if you use the `setTag(int, int)` method only.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy setTag(int,Object) if that object is view only or itcan be anything say a String would cause problem and moreover setTag() we can use view or it is ViewHolder class that contain views. and I would love to know if you can paste some code in which you have done both the things according to android version or you made separate adapters?

Comment: `setTag(int, Object)` will still cause leaks, but if it's not a View instance, there won't be too much of a problem. It's only when the tag has a reference to a `Context` that will cause issues as it will end up leaking the `Activity`.

Comment: However, in `setTag()`, if you want to retain just a single reference to a View, you can use the `View` as the tag directly. Otherwise, write a  `ViewHolder` class to encapsulate the `View` references you need.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy Thanks :) Can you tell me more about how you find that view will cause leaking of an activity and also does tag makes any effects on list view scroll

Comment: And no, tag by itself shouldn't be having an effect on listview scroll. What has an effect is what you do in getView()/bindView()

Comment: I have created getView() only and Its working: how it is possible, Can you explain.?? Link is here: http://pastebin.com/W9FBG7Wt

Comment: CursorAdapter is a subclass of baseAdapter, and thus, it implements getView() on it's own. You have just overriden that method, and hence, it will work.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy What to do if i have to use `ViewHolder` and `SubViewHolder`, Once i have inflate layout from `newView` but what about their child layout?