# Android EditText going to blank when i hide soft input keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-gridview

I have previously posted

1. [EditText in GridView : How to get value from Multiple EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19196322/1318946)
2. [Android : newView() and bindView() with SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226186/1318946)

I got a little bit of success on the second question but I have one more problem like:

My `GridView` has 1 `ImageView`, 1 `TextView` and 3 `EditText`, when I am pressing the back button for hiding soft input keyboard, I got the blank value of every EditText.

#### **Showing images:**

#### **1.First time Viewing GridView:**

[image: First time Viewing GridView]

#### **2.While filling up value of EditText:**

[image: While filling up value of EditText]

#### **3.Click on Next of Soft Input Keyboard, Its displaying QWERT keypad:**

[image: Its displaying QWERT keypad]

#### **4.Cleaning all Edited EditText :**

[image: Clear all EditText]

What is the reason behind this??

Please help,

You help would be appreciated...

Comment: Finally I got solution that I have changed `SimpleCursorAdapter` to `BaseAdapter` and stored `Cursor` value to `ArrayList`

Comment: But it's not solution, I want to keep data when keyboard hide.