# Adding a header to a ListView row or appending a header to group of items

Tags: android, android-listview

I went through a lot of articles on this subject of how to separate the items and group them under one header. Of all I liked the idea of making  a header visible and invisible depending whether to show it or not. I also know that this magic happens in the bindView/newView method of the custom adapter class. So far so good. Now I am querying the Database for dates, I want items falling under a unique date to be grouped together under a Date heading. (That is I want to group items by date) Is there a way I can check dates in if else conditions (Dates fetched from cursor) and depending on these I group them together. One such article on the subject I found was[This](http://kmansoft.com/2010/11/16/adding-group-headers-to-listview/). However I am not able to understand it completely. For me an Algorithm to do the same would work.

So far this is my code:

```
private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
        //  Context context; 
        //  Cursor c; 
        public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);

            //      this.context = context; 
            //      this.c= c; 

        }


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
            TextView tV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            TextView tV1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
            TextView tV2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView iM = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 

            tV1.setTypeface(tf); 
            tV2.setTypeface(tf); 

            tV.setText(dateConvert(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))));
            String B = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationFor")); 
            tV1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationDateFor")));



            if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 


            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 


            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 


            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 


            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("5")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 


            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 


            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("7")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 

            }


        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_list, parent, false);
            bindView(v, context, c);
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Essentially I want a way to check what the DateToNotify holds for each row, depending on this I will show of hide the view. Any Hints?

**EDIT**

So far this is what I have tried, although I get the desired result but scrolling the list messes up everything:

```
@Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {

            TextView tV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            TextView tV1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
            TextView tV2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView iM = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 

            tV1.setTypeface(tf); 
            tV2.setTypeface(tf); 


            if(tV.getText().toString().equals(dateConvert(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))))){


                tV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
            }else{
                tV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

                tV.setText(dateConvert(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))));
            }
```

**EDIT**

Optimized Code as per[This Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672749/what-bindview-and-newview-do-in-cursoradapter)

```
@Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {


            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.detail_list, null);
            //bindView(v, context, c);
            TextView tV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            TextView tV1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
            TextView tV2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView iM = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 
            RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.relative1); 

            view.setTag(R.id.textView1, tV); 
            view.setTag(R.id.textView2, tV1); 
            view.setTag(R.id.textView3, tV2); 
            view.setTag(R.id.imageView2, iM); 
            view.setTag(R.id.relative1, RL); 
            return view;
        }
```

And BindView:

```
@Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {

            ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setTypeface(tf); 
            ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView3)).setTypeface(tf); 
        //  RelativeLayout RL =(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.relative1); 
            String Bb = ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString(); 
            if(Bb.equals(dateConvert(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))))){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "If Condition: "+Bb, 10000).show(); 
                ((RelativeLayout)view.getTag(R.id.relative1)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

            }else{

                ((RelativeLayout)view.getTag(R.id.relative1)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

                ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setText(dateConvert(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))));
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution customized for your problem: (Based on the Link you provided)

```
private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_START = 0;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_CONT = 1;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

        LayoutInflater mInflater ;
        public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


        }


        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_START;
            }
            Cursor cursor = getCursor();
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            boolean newGroup = isNewGroup(cursor, position);

            if (newGroup) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_START;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_CONT;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {

            TextView tV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            TextView tV1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
            TextView tV2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ImageView iM = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 
            tV1.setTypeface(tf); 
            tV2.setTypeface(tf); 
            if(tV!=null)
                tV.setText(dateConvert(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))));


            String B = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationFor")); 
            tV1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationDateFor")));


            if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.XXX); 

            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 

            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){

                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");

                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 

            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){

                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 

            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("5")){

                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 

            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX"); 
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 

            }else if(B.equalsIgnoreCase("7")){

                tV2.setText("Is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NotificationData"))+" XXX");
                iM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_XXX); 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            int position = cursor.getPosition();
            int nViewType;

            if (position == 0) {
                nViewType = VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_START;
            } else {
                boolean newGroup = isNewGroup(cursor, position);
                if (newGroup) {
                    nViewType = VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_START;
                } else {
                    nViewType = VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_CONT;
                }
            }

            View v;

            if (nViewType == VIEW_TYPE_GROUP_START) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_list, parent, false);

                View vHeader = v.findViewById(R.id.relativeSecondary);
                vHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                    }
                });
            } else {

                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_list_no_header, parent, false);
            }
            return v;
        }


        private boolean isNewGroup(Cursor cursor, int position) {
            String ThisDate = dateConvert(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))); 
            cursor.moveToPosition(position - 1);
            String compareDate = dateConvert(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DateToNotify"))); 
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);    
            if (!ThisDate.equalsIgnoreCase(compareDate)) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```